# python json search from multiple URLs

Tags: python, json

i have tow urls or json file and both have the same ID looks this.

file1

```
{
    {
    "code": 200,
    "students": [
        {
            "student": "John, Doe",
            "Total Marks": "79%",
            "math": 55,
            "Sience": 56

        },
        {
            "student": "Jame, George",

            "Total Marks": "99%",
            "math": 55,
            "Sience": 56
        }
    ]
}
```

file2

```
{
     {
    "code": 200,
    "students": [
        {
            "student": "John, Bill",
            "Total Marks": "69%",
            "math": 58,
            "Sience": 46

        },
        {
            "student": "Joe, Ham",

            "Total Marks": "49%",
            "math": 25,
            "Sience": 26
        }
    ]
}
```

i want to search for student name on both json from URL to get the marks.
for example i want to Search for John i should get both John Doe and Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. You can use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON, and fix any errors.

Your JSON should look like the below after validating:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "students": [
        {
            "student": "John",
            "Total Marks": "79%",
            "math": 55,
            "Sience": 56

        },
        {
            "student": "Jame",
            "Total Marks": "99%",
            "math": 55,
            "Sience": 56
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the JSON was missing a couple of `"` quotes and had extra `,` commas trailing in each object, which will cause errors when deserializing your JSON to an object. For demonstration purposes, I will show how to read JSON from a file called `data.json`.

First we can make a function that goes through a JSON array and finds a student based on a given *name*:

```
def get_student(data, name):
    for item in data:
        if item["student"] == name:
            return item
```

We can also have it return a list of names using a *list comprehension*:

```
def get_student(data, name):
    return [item for item in data if item["student"] == name]
```

Then we can open the JSON file with a `with` context manager and deserialize the JSON with [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load). We can then call `get_student()` on the `students` JSON array:

```
from json import load
from json import JSONDecodeError

with open("C:\\data.json") as json_file:
    try:
        data = load(json_file)
        print(get_student(data["students"], 'John'))
    except JSONDecodeError as ex:
        print(ex)
```

Which returns the following student object:

```
{'student': 'John', 'Total Marks': '79%', 'math': 55, 'Sience': 56}
```

If no student was found, `get_student()` will simply return `None`. I also used `try..except` to catch and print any errors with the JSON deserialization, which will trigger a [`json.JSONDecodeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecodeError) exception if the JSON file is invalid.

### Update from Question

For making the above work with multiple JSON files(Just 2 in this case, as updated in your question), you can try out the below code. It adds extra logic to split the names by `","` and compare the first names. To make sure names like `John` and `john` are considered *equal*, we can make both first names lowercase with `.lower()`. Additionally, It is better design to make first names and last names separate fields however.

```
from json import load
from json import JSONDecodeError

def get_student_by_firstname(data, first_name):
    for item in data:
        try:
            firstname, _ = map(str.strip, item["student"].split(","))
        except ValueError:
            firstname = item["student"].strip()

        if firstname.lower() == first_name.lower():
            return item

files = [
    "C:\\data1.json",
    "C:\\data2.json"
]

for path in files:
    with open(path) as json_file:
        try:
            json_data = load(json_file)
            print(get_student_by_firstname(json_data["students"], first_name="John"))
        except JSONDecodeError as ex:
            print(ex)
```

**Output:**

```
{'student': 'John, Doe', 'Total Marks': '79%', 'math': 55, 'Sience': 56}
{'student': 'John, Bill', 'Total Marks': '69%', 'math': 58, 'Sience': 46}
```